# Can't vote on MSO

Tags: bug, status-completed

Any time I try to vote on a question, answer, or comment on MSO today I get an error to the effect of "An error occurred during voting" or "An error has occurred - please retry your request". So far, this seems to be the only site I'm having problems on, but I've also had other users confirm it.

Comment: Related: https://twitter.com/marcgravell/status/408955492401045505

Comment: You get an error but the vote does come through.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Fix <s>is already being</s> has already been deployed; we changed some libs - things broke. Badness. All good imminently.

Comment: hahahaha - I tried to upvote this and it failed :-)

Comment: @RoryAlsop I said "being", not "been" - our build server says 40 seconds more; edit: *now* it is "been"

Comment: I know - I was being impatient. #attentionspanofagoldfish